# @RequestBody doesn't convert nested object from payload into an entity that has an @ManyToMany variable

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I'm attempting to make a PUT request through curl. Within the payload I send through curl, I have a nested object that I want Spring to read as an entity. But, when I send the payload through a controller and after @RequestBody reads the payload, Spring fails to convert this nested object into my desired entity. (Spring returns null)

This is my curl command(abridged):

```
curl -X PUT ... --data "{
  ...
  \"playlistValue\":{
    \"1\":{
      \"filename\":\"test.mp4\",
      \"id\":\"2\"},
    \"2\":{
      \"filename\":\"test2.mp4\",
       \"id\":\"1\"}}}"
```

The object that is the value of \"playlistValue\" is another entity that exists in Spring. That entity is Video. The entity that I'm making the PUT request to is Playlist.

```
@Entity
public class Playlist {
    private @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="playlist_id") 
    long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="playlist_values",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="playlist_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="video_id"))
    private Map<Integer, Video> playlistValue;
}

@Entity
public class Video {
    private @GeneratedValue @Id @Column(name="video_id") Long id;
    private @ManyToMany(mappedBy= "playlistValue") Set<Playlist> playlists;
}
```

I want Spring to be able to convert the nested object I send through the payload in curl into another entity, Video. If there is a different way to make a PUT request, then how?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make my PUT request by putting this in the controller:

```
@RequestBody Map<Integer,Video> newPlaylist...
```

Instead of this:

```
@RequestBody Playlist ...
```

Spring was able to convert the Video in the Map to a Video entity, and thus I was able to do my PUT request by using @PathVariable to search for the Id of my Playlist,setting it, and then saving it.

Comment: Maybe it's because playListValue is nested inside another object? 
I'm just assuming, but I think that building the request with the root object not enclosed would make it work